# Create an index on a MySQL column based on the length its contents?

Tags: mysql, indexing, myisam

How do I create an index on a column in MySQL v 5.0 (myisam db engine) based upon the length of its value its a TEXT data type up to 7000 characters, do I have to add another column with the length of the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as MySQL doesn't support function-based indexes (like `ADD INDEX myIndex(LENGTH(text)))`, you'll need a new int column and define a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) to auto-update it after inserts and updates.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good approach to me (sorry don't know mysql, but in oracle you could set a trigger so that when your main column is updated the "length" column gets automatically updated)