# Slow Query on Medium MySQL Table (1 Million Rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a MySQL table with around 1 million rows. The table name is `dedict` When I run a simple query like:

```
select writtenform from dedict where length(writtenform)>5 
    and partofspeech <> 'abbreviation' order by id asc limit 50,1
```

the query takes around 1 second.

I have as primary key the `id` column (autoincrement) and an index on `writtenForm`.

Below you see the results of `explain dedict`:

```
Field               Type                Null    Key     Default     Extra
senseid             varchar(255)        NO      NULL    
writtenForm         varchar(255)        YES     MUL     NULL
languageIdentifier  varchar(255)        YES     NULL        
partOfSpeech        varchar(255)        YES     NULL
_index              int(11)             YES     NULL
writtenText         longtext            YES     NULL
lexiconid           varchar(255)        YES     NULL
id                  int(11)             NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
```

There must be something wrong. I have to run this query 5 times to show a webpage so the load time is more than 5 seconds.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you change the structure of the table ?

Comment: I do not understand why people choose keywords to name table's columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84346/create-an-index-on-a-mysql-column-based-on-the-length-its-contents  the index on writtenfrom is usless unless its an index based on length.

Comment: So is it enough just to add a new column with the length of writtenform? Then I should simply index this new column or there is something more?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support indexes based on length, so creating a trigger and another attributes makes as index will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can optimize the attribute length. There are 5 attributes of type varchar(255).

In any case, to get something incredibly faster, you can create a trigger on insert/update statement to store the content length in another attribute.
So each time a row is inserted or updated the trigger store the length in another column of type integer.

Moreover, do you really need to query all the table at a time ?

Comment: Well this table is for a dictionary. It contains most of the words in one language. I don't plan to update it. So, should I add a new column with the writtenform length? Does it help? Regarding the other question, I want to show 5 random words on all the pages. That's why I query it 5 times.

Comment: Adding a new column to store the length will be faster because you will compare an integer to another integer (and not two strings).

Comment: "length(writtenform)>5" retrieves the size of the attribute then makes a comparison. "partofspeech <> 'abbreviation'" is a comparison too. You should try to do not compare strings to prevent performance  issues.

Comment: If spreading 'partOfSpeech' in another table and saving only the id in the 'dedict' table makes sens you should do it. Because if you store 'abbreviation' many times as keyword it's redundant. But this choice depends on your schema.

Comment: @CatalinMarcu Your query doesn't just get the 50th row.  You get the 50th row that meets two characteristics.  The DB has no idea what `partofspeech` is until it looks, no ide how long `writtenform` is until it looks, and no idea how long it will have to look until it finds 50.  Since `LONGTEXT` is a BLOB data type, it's very inefficient to query against with functions (the tradeoff of allowing over 4 GB of text in that single field value).  BLOBs aren't meant for that.  Think of it like finding the 50th ordered number in an unordered sequence that satisfies `4x^3 + x^2 is divisble by 7`.

Comment: I got it. I will create more tables: partofspeech, writtentext and then join these tables when needed. Moreover I will add a new column containing the writtenform length. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the structure of the table

like--senseid  to integer
writtenForm  ---should have add indexed to this bcoz u r using this column for manipulating the data .

Comment: I cannot change senseid to integer, because lateron I join other tables on senseid

Answer (score 0):

I have restructured the existing table and created more tables in the schema. Now the query runs in less than 10 ms.
The new `dedict` table looks like this (I have suppressed the `writtenform` column and changed the types of `languageIdentifier`, `partOfSpeech` and `lexiconid`):

```
Field               Type                Null    Key     Default     Extra
senseid             varchar(255)        NO      NULL    
languageIdentifier  tinyint             YES     NULL        
partOfSpeech        tinyint             YES     NULL
_index              int(11)             YES     NULL
writtenText         longtext            YES     NULL
lexiconid           tinyint             YES     NULL
id                  int(11)             NO      PRI     NULL        auto_increment
```

Additionally I have created four tables for joining: `writtenForm`, `languageIdentifier`, `partOfSpeech` and `lexiconid`. Three of these tables are really little (`dedict_lang` has 2 records, `dedict_partOfSpeech` has 37 records and `dedict_lexicon` has 4 records), while the `dedict_writtenForm` which only contain the `id`, the `writtenForm` itself and the length of `writtenForm` is 1 million records, but correctly indexed.